# Server can't find domain: SERVFAIL

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, centos, domain

I have VPS and CentOS7 installed on it. Also I have httpd Apache2, nginx, named and iptables services working there. First, when I just bought this server, I had hostname `maindomain1.com` and made my own NS servers based on this `maindomain1.com`. Then I decided to change my own NS servers to another - `maindomain2.com`, but left the hostname `maindomain1.com`. Everything was working fine until I noticed, that I left hostname with old domian name and decided to find any mention of `maindomain1.com` and replace it with `maindomain2.com` including hostname. And now I have the following problem: I can only resolve `maindomain2.com`, any other domain/website which uses ns1.maindomain2.com and ns2.maindomain2.com can't be resolved or loaded in web browser.

```
[root@maindomain2 ~]# nslookup maindomain2.com
Server:         (IP here)
Address:        (IP here)

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   maindomain2.com
Address: (IP here)
```

But

```
[root@maindomain2 ~]# nslookup userdomain.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find userdomain.com: SERVFAIL
```

`userdomain.com` has NS records: ns1.maindomain2.com and ns2.maindomain2.com

`zone "userdomain.com" {type master; file "/path-to-file/userdomain.com.db";};` contains:

```
$TTL 14400
@    IN    SOA    ns1.maindomain2.com.    root.userdomain.com. (
                                            2020041504
                                            7200
                                            3600
                                            1209600
                                            180 )

@   14400   IN  NS      ns1.maindomain2.com.
@   14400   IN  NS      ns2.maindomain2.com.
@   14400   IN  A       (IP here)
mail    14400   IN  A       (IP here)
www 14400   IN  A       (IP here)
pop 14400   IN  A       (IP here)
ftp 14400   IN  A       (IP here)
@   14400   IN  MX  10  mail.userdomain.com.
@   14400   IN  TXT     "v=spf1 a mx ip4:(IP here) ?all"
_dmarc  14400   IN  TXT     "v=DMARC1; p=none"
```

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
options timeout:3 attempts:3
# Generated by NetworkManager
search com
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver (IP here)
nameserver (IP here)
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
(IP here) maindomain2.com
#127.0.0.1 maindomain2.example.com
```

`dig @(IP here) userdomain.com NS` is empty

`dig @(IP here) maindomain2.com NS`:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
maindomain2.com.           14400   IN      NS      ns2.maindomain2.com.
maindomain2.com.           14400   IN      NS      ns1.maindomain2.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.maindomain2.com.       14400   IN      A       (IP here)
ns2.maindomain2.com.       14400   IN      A       (IP here)
```

I'm new to networking, just wanted to change hostname. Where to dig to resolve this issue?

**UPD: Found the rude solution:** delete `userdomain` and create it again (in my case via VESTA CP). It works. But what if I would have a lot of data on this domain. I would like to find the source of this issue for future cases and for people who can't just delete domain. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Did you remember to register the nameservers with the maindomain2.com registrar?

Comment: @MrLumute yes, sure. ns1.maindomain2.com IP1, ns2.maindomain2.com IP2.

Comment: could it be a dnssec issue?

Comment: @Jasen I don't think so, I didn't set it up.

Comment: **Found the rude solution:** delete `userdomain` and create it again (in my case via VESTA CP). It works. But what if I would have a lot of data on this domain. I would like to find the source of this issue for future cases and for people who can't just delete domain. Does anybody have any ideas?